# opensuse sudo bash completion gives full path names

Tags: bash, sudo, opensuse, autocomplete

There is this weird behavior with my openSUSE system whenever I try to run a program with sudo:

What I type:

```
sudo shutd<TAB>
```

Expected it to return:

```
sudo shutdown
```

But what I got is this:

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown
```

How do I set it so that the bash completion does not return the full path name of the program?

FYI: I haven't made any config changes (that includes modifying files in /etc) to the system.

Comment: Is there a particular problem with the full path?

Comment: Well, I just find it a little annoying and also, normal versions of openSUSE do not give the full path on sudo.